# How to stack Flutter selection pointer over keyboard?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I tried using stack widget but it's not work.

[image]

I see some references from native Android, and there's no error like this.

[image]

source code

```
const Expanded(
                    child: Scrollbar(
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Write a message...',
                        ),
                        maxLines: 6,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                        minLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: what do you mean by ``stack Flutter selection pointer on keyboard``?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I already edit my question. my question mean when you see my selection pointer is not stack over keyboard such, I used stack widget but it's not work

Comment: Do you mean to say that the pointer is behind the keyboard and not on the top of the keyboard? @FajraRisqulla

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, so what should I do to solve this problem?